# How do I make Flutter Widget disappear after certain time (in days)?

Tags: flutter, datetime, time, widget

I have few widgets on home screen, one of them is there only if user save some data, from that moment
I want to count 7 days and if nothing else happen widget will be deleted.
I tried something like this:

//When user save data to widget

```
  _saveTime() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    pref.setString(
        'StoreTime', DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 8)).toString());
  }
```

Then in the Home page

```
...
bool _thirdMenu;
String _difDays = '';

 @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
  _thirdMenu = true;
  
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    _init();
}

  _init() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String oldTimePref = pref.getString('StoreTime') ?? '1969-07-20 20:18:04Z';
    DateTime oldTime = DateTime.parse(oldTimePref);
    DateTime newTime = DateTime.now();
    var difference = oldTime.difference(newTime);
    if (difference.inDays > 0) {
      setState(() {
        _thirdMenu = true;
        _difDays = difference.inDays.toString();
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _thirdMenu = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

Not working, time stay the same and widget still showing...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with days, I think you can work without hours and minutes.
You can isolate the days and check without using time difference.

```
int oldDay = oldTime.day;
int today = newTime.day;
if(today - oldDay >= 7) {
  setState(() {
        _thirdMenu = false;
      });
} else {
  setState(() {
        _thirdMenu = true;
      });
}
```

Comment: IM getting "today - oldDay = 22" (coz oldtime is day saved + 8 but in calendar so if saved on 25+8, came up to 3 (03.07)  . Olso I need to show how many days remaining  so I need difference...